# authorization in MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have login page in MVC project and i created authorization config this.

```
  <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880"  defaultUrl="~/Home/Index"/>
    </authentication>

  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
```

How can i access in register page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on what version of MVC you're using the common practice I see now in MVC3/4 is to instead of restricting access to specific actions, to restrict access to all actions, by adding `Authorize()` as a global filter and then grant access to a few select actions using the `AllowAnonymous()` attribute to act as a white-list of actions that do not need to be protected. (Like Login, Register, etc).

**global.asax**

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
}
```

**AccountsController.cs**

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login()
{
    //Perform login...
}
```

Then you're **web.config** just has this

```
<authorization>
    <allow users="*" />
</authorization>
```

Comment: this is windows authorization?

Comment: It could be. But this is just the Authorization to determine who can access what. The user might still be Authenticated using Windows Authentication. There's a subtle difference in the word but the two are different. Authentication is the act of proving who you are (logging in) and that's it. Authorization is the part that determines what you can do. This question is just for the Authorization, while the Authentication could be Windows, Forms, or some other external service like OpenAuth.

Answer (score 0):

By default you should go to `Register()` action method of `Account` controller

> // GET: /Account/Register

According to your web.config: try to add this to web.config before `<system.web>` tag.

```
 <location allowOverride="true" path="Account/Register">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?" />
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Comment: It work fine for me in the newly created project, what error did you got, or incorrect behavior?

Answer (score 0):

A +1 to Nick Albrecht, but I found ambiguity with "filters" so I had to dig further.

Actually, it appears that 
    `filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());`
this code belongs in App_Start

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        filters.Add(new AuthorizeTokens.AuthorizeWithMessage());
    }
}
```

and `FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters)` is called in Application_Start.